# alert img's src attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<img id="myImg" src="image.jpg" />
<script>
alert(
//code that pop myImg src attribute 
);
</script>
```

I need  to get alert with the image's src attribute

Comment: google "jquery how to get attribute" you lazy bum

Comment: Did you expend any effort whatsoever trying to find the answer for this question yourself? The jQuery documentation is a pretty good resource; I'd recommend perusing it before posting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get the value of specified attribute:

```
alert($('#myImg').attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript.

```
alert(document.getElementById("myImg").src);
```